# Redirect with cookies

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, redirect, cookies

Is it possible to redirect to other domain with cookies? I tried followong.

```
def test_redirect
  response.headers['Cache-Control'] = 'no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate'
  response.headers['Pragma'] = 'no-cache'
  response.headers['Expires'] = '0'

  request.cookies[:foo] = {value: 'Viktor is here!', domain: '.google.com'}

  redirect_to 'http://google.com/'
end
```

But it didn't work. My cookie doesn't appear.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot set cookies for another domain. Allowing this would present an enormous security flaw.